# C - Cannot execute function with pointers

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, function-pointers

Hey guys this is my first time using stack overflow :D
I'm getting this error:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0105F338 (ucrtbased.dll) in Assignment_5.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.
>
> Exception thrown at 0x0105F338 (ucrtbased.dll) in Assignment_5.exe:
>   0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xCDCDCDCD.

This is the main:

```
void Test2(char* arr[], int size_arr, char* str, int size_res, char* str_cmp)
{
    int size_res_new;
    char** tempStringArr = LowerSTR(arr, size_arr, str, &size_res_new);

    if (tempStringArr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Can't allocate arr (-4)\n");
        return;
    }

    if (size_res_new != size_res)
    {
        printf("The amount of string is not correct (-4)\n");
        return;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < size_res; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(tempStringArr[i], str_cmp) == 0)
        {
            return;
        }
    }
    printf("No String: %s (-4)\n", str_cmp);
}
```

This is the function:

```
char** LowerSTR(char* arr[], int size_arr, char* str, int* size_res)
{
    char** newArr = NULL, counter=0;
    newArr = (char**)malloc(size_arr * sizeof(char*));
    if(newArr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size_arr; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(arr[i], str) < 0) {
            newArr[counter] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(arr[i]));
            if (newArr[counter] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            strcpy(newArr[counter], arr[i]);
        }
        else
            counter++;
    }
    *size_res = size_arr - counter;
    newArr = (char**)realloc(newArr, sizeof(char*) * (*size_res));
    return newArr;
}
```

Comment: `0xCDCDCDCD` is _Used by Microsoft's C/C++ debug malloc() function to mark uninitialized heap memory, usually returned from HeapAlloc()_ In other words, you didn't allocate something. The debugger will tell you which line in your code the error occurs at.

Answer (score 1):

```
        newArr[counter] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * strlen(arr[i])); // allocate strlen(arr[i]) bytes
        if (newArr[counter] == NULL)
        {
            printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
            exit(0);
        }
        strcpy(newArr[counter], arr[i]); // copy 1+strlen(arr[i]) bytes. oops.
```

You allocate `strlen(arr[i])` bytes but then you try to copy `arr[i]` into the buffer you allocated. But it has one byte too few because a string has a nul character on the end. You need to allocate one more byte. A tool like valgrind should have told you about this.

Answer (score 0):

In your `LowerSTR` function, you modify the `counter` variable in the `else` portion, but it should be in the `if` portion. Otherwise, you are incrementing it leaving *bad* values in the `newArr` function, and overwriting previously good values. This results in several values being overwritten by your `realloc`. The function should be more like the following:

```
char** LowerSTR(char* arr[], int size_arr, char* str, int* size_res)
{
    char** newArr = NULL, counter=0;
    newArr = (char**)malloc(size_arr * sizeof(char*));
    if(newArr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
        exit(0);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<size_arr; i++)
    {
        if (strcmp(arr[i], str) < 0) {
            newArr[counter] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * (strlen(arr[i]) + 1));
            if (newArr[counter] == NULL)
            {
                printf("Memory not allocated.\n");
                exit(0);
            }
            strcpy(newArr[counter], arr[i]);
            ++counter;
        }
    }
    *size_res = counter;
    newArr = (char**)realloc(newArr, sizeof(char*) * (*size_res));
    return newArr;
}
```